# Validating protobuf using json schema

Tags: protocol-buffers, jsonschema

Are there any examples / references to see how protobuf data can be validated using json schema?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I'm starting off with something too basic...

Protobuf data can be validated using protobuf deserialisers; if data is parsed by the parser that was generated for the message (and is part of the class representing that message), then it's valid data. To generate that parser / class, you'd have started with a protobuf schema and compiled that with protoc.

Generally speaking, I'd say that wanting to validate such data against a json schema is possibly not a good idea. The point is that, to also have a json schema for the same data is to then have "two versions of the truth", which is generally a bad idea. Which one is right; the .proto schema, or the json schema? If I edit one, have I accurately edited the other?

**JSON Can Do More Than Protobuf**

I can see why you may want to check such data against a json schema. In a json schema you can define things like value and size constraints that cannot be expressed in a protobuf schema. For example, a message field "bearing" might in the application have a limited valid value between 0 and 359. There is no way to implement such a constraint in protobuf, but if expressed in a json schema used to validate json data, the validator would object if "bearing" were set to 412.

So, why not generate code from the json schema? I have tried (some time ago - I'm out of date) code generators for languages like C# using json schema as input, but found the result unsatisfactory (the code generators I tried didn't want to implement all the things in my json schema, e.g. unions). Things may have got a lot better since then.

**Is there a Better Solution?**

If this is indeed the kind of thing you need to do, then it's likely that choosing protobuf is not ideal for the purpose (due to the lack of constraints in protobuf schema). The question then is, what are the alternatives?

In my experience, if you want to stick to the concept of starting with a schema and generating code, the best I've ever used is ASN.1 (where "best" assumes you're willing to pay for good commercial ASN.1 tools from companies like Objective Systems or Nokalva - I've been a customer of both).

These days, ASN.1 can even serialise to json (or xml in several flavours, or other text and packed / unpacked binary data formats). The ASN.1 schema language does have constraints on sizes of lists and/or values of fields. There is an official translation between ASN.1 schema and XML schema (XSD), with the better ASN.1 tools able to do that translation. There may now be an defined translation between ASN.1 and json schema too (I don't know), plus tools to do that.

The point of that is, with translation tools, one can then say that the ASN.1 schema and XSD (or json) schema are "one single truth" - one being automatically generated from the other which was hand written.

**A Good Halfway Hosue?**

I notice (from a quick search) that there are various git* projects purporting to translate between protobuf and json schema, which if satisfactory means that your json and protocol buffer schema can be automatically translated between one and the other (which means that my 2nd para above is junk!).

Unless something has happened recently, those json protobuf schema translations are going to be limited, or disappointing. ASN.1, XSD and json schema are broadly similar in terms of what their syntaxes allow to be expressed (including size and value constraints), so translation between them doesn't necessarily lose "information". However, the syntax of protobuf schema is a lot more limited than that of json schema, so a translation from json schema to protobuf might lose the very information that you want.

The good news though would be that the protobuf schema would still be a "form of the truth" having been translated from the json schema. If you were using protobuf to generate json data instead of protobuf binary format data, the "original form of the truth" (the json schema) can be used to validate the protobuf generated json, with constraints on value and size still intact. That would be a good result!

Good luck!